# Yii2 dektrium add new field to user model and change it in account form

Tags: yii2

I have added a new field to user model 'paypal' and need to change it in overridden account form.

Override user model

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

class User extends \dektrium\user\models\User
{
    public function scenarios()
    {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios['create'][]   = 'paypal';
        $scenarios['update'][]   = 'paypal';
        $scenarios['register'][] = 'paypal';
        return $scenarios;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = parent::rules();
        $rules['paypalLength']   = ['paypal', 'string', 'max' => 255];

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Override SettingsForm model

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

class SettingsForm extends \dektrium\user\models\SettingsForm
{
    public $paypal;

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = parent::rules();
        $rules['paypalLength']   = ['paypal', 'string', 'max' => 255];
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Configure module

```
'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            'modelMap' => [
                'User' => 'common\models\User',
                'RegistrationForm' => 'common\models\RegistrationForm',
                'SettingsForm' => 'common\models\SettingsForm',
            ],
            'controllerMap' => [
...
```

And I have overridden account form view. When I'm trying to change paypal field in user/settings/account it doesn't change it. What should I do to make it work?
Thanks.

Comment: Here is its tutorial hope to help:
https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/master/docs/adding-new-field-to-user-model.md

Answer (score 0):

Also you must override `view` paths:

```
'view' => [
    'theme' => [
        'pathMap' => [
            '@dektrium/user/views' => '@app/views/user',
        ],
    ],
],
```

And after that open `@vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/views` and make a folder on `@app/views` based on `dektrium` view folders. For example create a folder named `admin` (because you have on `@vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/views` a folder named `admin`) and create corresponded folder on app views, i.e. `@app/views/admin`.

After that create your view file that you want to change on `@app/views/[dektrium-folder]` and change it.